# How to get common maximum element from three tables

Tags: mysql, sql, hive

I have three tables called table a, table b and table c
all the three tables have one common column.

How to get the common maximum value from the three tables?

here is my table info:

table a

```
id  salary
101  10000
102  15000
103  18000
```

table b

```
id salary
110  14000
127  21000
118  15000
```

table c

```
id  salary
191  15000
192  20000
193   8000
```

my required output is :

```
salary

15000
```

Comment: `UNION [ALL]` the three of them and then calculate your `MAX()`.  What seems to be the problem?

Answer (score 4):

Use `UNION ALL` (or `UNION`) to get the salaries of all 3 tables with an extra column, like an `id`, which marks the source table and then in the `HAVING` clause of an aggregation query check if that salary belongs to all tables.
Finally use `ORDER BY` with `LIMIT 1` to get the max common `salary`:

```
SELECT salary
FROM (
  SELECT 1 id, salary FROM tableA UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 id, salary FROM tableB UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 id, salary FROM tableC 
) t
GROUP BY salary
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT id) = 3 -- get only the common salaries
ORDER BY salary DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use inner joins between the tables to make sure you're only considering values that occur in all three tables.

Then use `MAX()` to get the greatest of such values.

```
SELECT MAX(salary) AS salary
FROM tableA JOIN tableB USING (salary) JOIN tableC USING (salary)
```